# SQLITE -- a file with 5,000,000 TINYINT values?

Tags: sqlite

I'd like to create a SQLITE file that includes 5,000,000 tinyint values (between 0 - 256).
According to my calculation, this file should use roughly 5[MB].

Yet, I am getting a file of size closer to 50[MB].

Here's the code that I use:

```python
import sqlite3
# Create and populate a database
db = sqlite3.connect('/home/mine/temp.db')
db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(id INT2)")
for i in range(0, 5000000):
     db.execute("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES({0})".format(0))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

Any ideas how to optimize things so that it takes much less space?

Comment: It depends on how many tables / indexes / a lot of things. Have you tried creating a DB?

Comment: I have, and got a huge file. Perhaps I am not proficient with SQLITE. Any suggestions?  (I only need one table; NO INDICES at all)

Comment: How huge is huge? 6MB? 50MB? Might be worth posting the code you used to generate the table. Then people can make concrete suggestions about how to optimise it.

Comment: Just noticed that you're substituting values into SQL. Don't do that. Use the prepared statement style instead (for integers it gives you a speedup, for strings — or anything from the outside world really — it also gives you safety).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a lot more to a database than just space for 5 million tiny ints. SQLite has published [details of their file format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#database_file_format). It seems to say you're going to need at least 9 bytes per row.

> SQLite uses two distinct variants of
>   the B-Tree structure:
>
> - The table B-Tree, which uses 64-bit
>     integer values for keys. In a table
>     B-Tree, an associated database record
>     (section 2.3.2) is stored along with
>     each entry. Table B-Tree structures
>     are described in detail in section
>     2.3.4.
> - The index B-Tree, which uses database records as keys. Index B-Tree
>     structures are described in detail in
>     section 2.3.3.

Comment: Thank you, this explains it all.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a two-column Value/Frequency table?  It'd make queries a little more complicated (e.g., you'd need `SUM(Value * Freq) / SUM(Freq)` instead of `AVG(Value)`), but you'd only need at most 256 rows instead of 5 million.

Comment: I don't understand how this solves the issue / how this saves me from having 5 millions rows. can you explain?

Comment: If, for example, you have 20000 occurrences of the number 42, you don't store 20000 rows of (42).  You store one row of (42, 20000).

Comment: I see. The truth is, I do need to know which `ID` results in which number. So this type of compression will not work for me.

Comment: Yes, that does make a big difference.  Might want to clarify your question by changing your table example to `(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Value INTEGER)`.